# Missing events on ReadConsoleInput in windows shell?

Tags: c, winapi, stdio

As I proceed in my (possibly vain) attempt to reimplement a curses style library that supports both *nix and windows under an MIT license, I've stumbled onto a problem reading terminal import using the windows api.

Basically, I don't get all the events I expect to, and I don't know why.

First I setup the terminal to be in non-buffering mode:

```
DWORD mode;
HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

// Save old mode
GetConsoleMode(hstdin, &mode);

// Set to no line-buffering, no echo, no special-key-processing
SetConsoleMode(hstdin, 0);
```

Then I use PeekConsoleInput and ReadConsoleInput in a loop to have a non blocking key press input; the equivalent of using termios.h and select on stdin in linux:

```
__EXPORT int sterm_read(void *state) {
  DWORD dwRead;
  INPUT_RECORD inRecords[1];
  PeekConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &inRecords[0], 1, &dwRead);
  if (dwRead > 0) {
    ReadConsoleInput(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &inRecords[0], 1, &dwRead);
    if (inRecords[0].EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
      if (inRecords[0].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) {
        return inRecords[0].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
      }
    }
  }
 return -1;
}
```

Ignore the state variable; that's so the api can accept an arbitrary state struct on various platforms.

Now if I try to use this code:

```
#include <sterm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define assert(v, msg) if (!v) { printf("FAILED! %s", msg); return 1; }
int main(void) {
  void *state = sterm_init();
  int i;
  char c;
  for (;;) {
    if ((c = sterm_read(state)) == 81) { // ie. press q to exit
      break;
    }
    if (c != -1) {
      sterm_write(state, &c, 1); // This is a thin wrapper around _write(1, ...)
    }
  }
  sterm_shutdown(state);
  return 0;
}
```

It almost works. I get the input character I press pushed out to the terminal... mostly.

Probably every 10th character press is recorded. If I type quickly, the API 'loses' events, and I get "HEO WLD" instead of "HELLO WORLD".

What's going on? Does ReadConsoleInput somehow clear the input buffer?

Am I doing something wrong? It seems almost like I'm only getting events based on a race condition which is 'is key pressed when PeekConsoleInput is called'.

...but surely that shouldn't be the case? The point of using these buffered I/O interfaces (instead of GetAsyncKeyState) is that the events should be buffered right?

Help!

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be that using C I/O functions is causing the C runtime library to read the console input, stealing the keystrokes you're expecting and sticking them in the C runtime's input buffer.  Try using WriteConsoleOutput or WriteFile for your output instead of _write.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I only see `_write` mentioned, which doesn't touch the console input buffer. Doug's sample code works for me, though more needs to be done to decode the key event properly, as exemplified in the published source for the C runtime's `_getwch` function.

Comment: @Doug: what compiler are you using?  Can you provide an MCVE?

Comment: First, if you want to know whether there are input events, you should call [GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683207(v=vs.85).aspx). Second, you're not checking the return value from `PeekConsoleInput` or `ReadConsoleInput`, so there's no telling whether an error might be occurring. Third, that's a *very* tight loop. You'll be burning 100% CPU while waiting for input. That seems extreme, and might very well be the cause of your problem: the CPU is spending all of its time asking for input, and the hardware can't get a word in edgewise.

Answer (score 1):

I also have discovered that events are not guaranteed to stay around to be read.
This makes sense because otherwise the OS would need to provide lots and lots of buffering space.

The best I can do to deal with this is this code to do my own buffering
but clearly pastes of more than 128 characters will often fail :

```
static int g_eaten_ct = 0;       /* Re-eaten char */
static int g_eaten_ix = -1;
static int g_eaten[128];


void reeat(int c)

{ g_eaten_ct += 1;
  g_eaten[g_eaten_ix + g_eaten_ct] = c;         /* save the char for later */
}


void flush_typah()

{ 
    g_eaten_ct = 0;
    g_eaten_ix = -1;

    while (_kbhit())
    (void)ttgetc();
}


int ttgetc()

{ if (g_eaten_ct > 0)
  { g_eaten_ct -= 1;
    return g_eaten[++g_eaten_ix];
  }
{ int totalwait = g_timeout_secs;
  int oix = -1;

  while (1)
  { int got,need;
    const DWORD lim = 1000;
    INPUT_RECORD rec[32];

    int cc = WaitForSingleObject(g_ConsIn, lim);
    switch(cc)
    { case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
              need = sizeof(g_eaten)/sizeof(g_eaten[0]) - oix;
              if (need > 32)
                need = 32;
              cc = ReadConsoleInput(g_ConsIn,&rec[0],need,(DWORD*)&got);
              if (cc && got > 0)
                break;  
#if _DEBUG
              { DWORD errn = GetLastError();
                if (errn != 6)
                  mlwrite("%pError %d %d ", cc, errn);
              }
#endif
              continue;
      case WAIT_TIMEOUT: 
#if _DEBUG
              if (g_got_ctrl)
              { g_got_ctrl = false;
                return (int)(CTRL | 'C');
              }
#endif
              if (--totalwait == 0)     // -w opt
                exit(2);
                            // drop through
      default:continue;
    }

  { int ix = -1;
    while (++ix < got)
    { INPUT_RECORD * r = &rec[ix];
      if      (r->EventType == KEY_EVENT && r->Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
      { int ctrl = 0;
        int keystate = r->Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState;
        if (keystate & (RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED | LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED)) 
        { ctrl |= CTRL;
          g_chars_since_ctrl = 0;
        }
  
      { int chr = r->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
        if (in_range(chr, 0x10, 0x12))
          continue;                           /* shifting key only */
      
        if (keystate & (RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED | LEFT_ALT_PRESSED))
          ctrl |= ALTD;
        else
          chr = r->Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar & 0xff;
  
        if (/*chr !=  0x7c && */ (chr | 0x60) != 0x7c)  // | BSL < or ^ BSL
        { int vsc = r->Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode;
          if      (in_range(vsc, SCANK_STT, 0x58))
          { ctrl |= SPEC;
            chr = scantokey[vsc - SCANK_STT];
          }
//        else if (in_range(vsc, 2, 10) && chr == 0)
//          chr = '0' - 1 + vsc;
        }
       
        if ((keystate & SHIFT_PRESSED) && ctrl)   // exclude e.g. SHIFT 7
          ctrl |= SHFT;
        
        g_eaten[++oix] = ctrl | (chr == 0xdd ? 0x7c : chr);
        ++g_chars_since_ctrl;
      }}
      else if (r->EventType == MENU_EVENT)
      { /*loglog1("Menu %x", r->Event.MenuEvent.dwCommandId);*/
      }
    }
    
    if (got == need && oix < sizeof(g_eaten) / sizeof(int))
    { PeekConsoleInput(g_ConsIn, &rec[0], 1, (DWORD*)&got);
      if (got > 0)
        continue;
    }

    if (oix >= 0)
    { g_eaten_ct = oix;
      g_eaten_ix = 0;
      return g_eaten[0];
    }
  }}
}}
```